# Random image generator one by one in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm learning JavaScript and I want to do this exercise in which I want to generate and show random images one by one with the interval of 1 second and 4 images in one row and total 3 rows and 12 images and once this cycle completes it must repeat again with a different images sequence below is the code which I write so far but it generates all images at once

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Random Image Generator</title>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="imageTimeOut();" style="max-width: 400px;">
<h2 style="color: blue">Random Image Generator</h2>
<br>
<span id="result"> </span>   
</body>  
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
var imgTimer;

function imageTimeOut(){
    imgTimer = setTimeout(getRandomImage, 1000);   
}

function getRandomImage() {
    //declare an array to store the images
    var randomImage = new Array();

    //insert the URL of images in array
    randomImage[0] = "images/1.png";
    randomImage[1] = "images/2.png";
    randomImage[2] = "images/3.png";
    randomImage[3] = "images/4.png";
    randomImage[4] = "images/5.png";
    randomImage[5] = "images/6.png";
    randomImage[6] = "images/7.png";
    randomImage[7] = "images/8.png";
    randomImage[8] = "images/9.png";
    randomImage[9] = "images/10.png";
    randomImage[10] = "images/11.png";
    randomImage[11] = "images/12.png";

    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        //generate a number and provide to the image to generate randomly
        var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomImage.length);
        //print the images generated by a random number
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += '<img src="' + randomImage[number] + '" style="width:100px" />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would split this up a bit.

**Part 1: Layout**

To get 3 rows with 4 images per row, I would use [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

You can declare `display: grid;` on your `<span id="result">` element. This will declare a grid container for the content you want to display.

Then you can also declare `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr)` to get 4 even responsive columns.

This will make sure you get a 3x4 grid for your 12 images.

If you want to set some space between the images in the grid, `grid-gap` is nice for this. Here is a sample of this:

```
#result {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

**Part 2: Randomize the image list**

You can make a small utility shuffle function (e.g. [Fisher-Yates algorithm](https://dev.to/codebubb/how-to-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript-2ikj)).

```
/**
 * @description
 * shuffles an array of strings
 * with the Fisher-Yates algorithm
 *
 * @param {string[]} array - array of image sources
 * @returns {string[]} - shuffled array copy of image sources
 */
const shuffleArray = (array) => {
  const _arrCopy = [...array];
  for (let i = _arrCopy.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [_arrCopy[i], _arrCopy[j]] = [_arrCopy[j], _arrCopy[i]];
  }
  return _arrCopy;
};
```

Then you can pass the list of images to this function when you are ready to reset the list.

**Part 3: Create DOM functions with timer**

See the runnable snippet below for this code.

---

```js
// START: dummy data -------------------------------
const base = "https://images.dog.ceo/breeds";
const twelveImages = [
  `${base}/terrier-australian/n02096294_3704.jpg`,
  `${base}/terrier-australian/n02096294_8531.jpg`,
  `${base}/terrier-bedlington/n02093647_930.jpg`,
  `${base}/terrier-border/n02093754_1722.jpg`,
  `${base}/terrier-border/n02093754_6082.jpg`,
  `${base}/terrier-cairn/n02096177_1569.jpg`,
  `${base}/terrier-cairn/n02096177_2703.jpg`,
  `${base}/terrier-cairn/n02096177_2913.jpg`,
  `${base}/terrier-cairn/n02096177_9528.jpg`,
  `${base}/terrier-dandie/n02096437_290.jpg`,
  `${base}/beagle/1271553739_Milo.jpg`,
  `${base}/cotondetulear/100_2013.jpg`
];

const wikiBase = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org'
const filepath = 'wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Sound-of-dog.ogg';
const audio = `${wikiBase}/${filepath}`;
const bark = () => {
  new Audio(audio).play();
}
// END: dummy data ---------------------------------

/**
 * @description
 * shuffles an array of strings
 * with the Fisher-Yates algorithm
 *
 * @param {string[]} array - array of image sources
 * @returns {string[]} - shuffled array copy of image sources
 */
const shuffleArray = (array) => {
  const _arrCopy = [...array];
  for (let i = _arrCopy.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [_arrCopy[i], _arrCopy[j]] = [_arrCopy[j], _arrCopy[i]];
  }
  return _arrCopy;
};

// --------------------------------------------

/**
 * @description
 * creates a new image element and appends it inside the given wrapper
 *
 * @param {HTMLElement} wrapper  - wrapper to append images to
 * @param {string}      imageSrc - image source to use
 * @returns {void}
 */
const appendNewImage = (wrapper, imageSrc) => {
  // create image element
  const img = document.createElement("img");
  // set image source
  img.src = imageSrc;
  // add woof sound
  img.onclick = bark;
  // append image to wrapper
  wrapper.append(img);
};


// run image generator program
const run = () => {
  let idx = 0;
  let images = shuffleArray(twelveImages);

  setInterval(() => {
    // select result wrapper
    const wrapper = document.getElementById("result");

    // if we've reached the end, do a reset
    if (idx === images.length) {
      // remove images from wrapper
      wrapper.innerHTML = "";
      // reshuffle images
      images = shuffleArray(twelveImages);
      // reset counter index
      idx = 0;
    }

    appendNewImage(wrapper, images[idx]);
    // increment image index
    idx += 1;

  }, 1000);
};

// start it
run();
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0px 40px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#result {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}


/*
  NOTE: 
  This is outside the scope of your question,
  but please note that this image CSS is just
  dummy CSS for this StackOverflow snippet.
  
  You will need to adjust this image CSS 
  to account for different viewports 
  and whatever aspect ratios your images have.

  Ideally, you can use responsive images.

  SEE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images
*/

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  object-fit: cover;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 1px #eee;
  transition: transform 250ms, box-shadow 250ms;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

img:active {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #eee;
}
```

```html
<span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what you're really trying to accomplish. Perhaps you should really just shuffle your array, and use `setInterval`:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q, hC, aC, rC, tC, shuffle; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id); mobile = /Mobi/i.test(nav.userAgent);
S = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
hC = (node, className)=>{
  return node.classList.contains(className);
}
aC = (node, ...classNames)=>{
  node.classList.add(...classNames);
  return aC;
}
rC = (node, ...classNames)=>{
  node.classList.remove(...classNames);
  return rC;
}
tC = (node, className)=>{
  node.classList.toggle(className);
  return tC;
}
shuffle = array=>{
  let a = array.slice(), i = a.length, n, h;
  while(i){
    n = Math.floor(Math.random()*i--); h = a[i]; a[i] = a[n]; a[n] = h;
  }
  return a;
}
// tiny library above - below can be put on another page using a load Event (except // end load line);
function fourImgsEvery(outputNode, imgArray, often = 1000){
  const a = shuffle(imgArray), img0 = M('img'), img1 = M('img'), img2 = M('img'), img3 = M('img'); // shuffle array and make images
  outputNode.appendChild(img0); outputNode.appendChild(img1); outputNode.appendChild(img2); outputNode.appendChild(img3);
  let i = 0, l = imgArray.length;
  return setInterval(()=>{ // returns interval so you can clear it
    if(i === l)i = 0;
    img0.src = a[i++]; img1.src = a[i++]; img2.src = a[i++]; img3.src = a[i++];
  }, often);
}
const images = ['https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGgv6.jpg?s=128&g=1', 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ee6e12042dc31b1ef27471482f9ff91f?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1',
'https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5UKi.jpg?s=128&g=1', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/xduoU.png?s=96&g=1', 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0555bd0deb416a320a0069abef08078a?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1', 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f00013ceab8fb1928885c5c172fbfd4a?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMDvl.jpg?s=128&g=1', 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6605deca5924e84df1a4847f607b87c6?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFOp5.jpg?s=96&g=1', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4fiW.jpg?s=96&g=1', 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/976f07be84907aad663ce8c1c51cf5c4?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HovX.jpg?s=128&g=1'];
const out = I('output');
fourImgsEvery(out, images);
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Random Images</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='output'></div>
</body>
</html>
```